# Android virtual device "no such file" launching problem

Tags: 14.04, java, android

When I launch my emulator I get this error:

> Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program /home/mahfuz(my computer name)/Android-Sdk(folder)/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory.

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: What does `ls -la /home/mahfuz(my computer name)/Android-Sdk(folder)/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running 64bit you need to install ia32-libs:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```